# Alternative option for cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-browser

I have been working on front end framework call "BackboneJs", I have used the cookie to store data in browser.

But in some case i need to store more data which does not supported by cookie.

Is anyone know the best option for storing considerable large data which cookie does not support.

Please suggest your ideas.

And yes it must be cross browser supported

Comment: What kind of data are we talking about. Why are you storing it in a cookie in the first place (use case)?

Comment: In front end some html content have to be generated by program, each time new html content generated because generation function has HASH. But once user has save its changes and come back same page, I need to show same, hence this problem arise.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to http://lucb1e.com/rp/cookielesscookies/ ,
This tracking method works without needing to use:

- Cookies
- Javascript
- LocalStorage/SessionStorage/GlobalStorage
- Flash, Java or other plugins
- Your IP address or user agent string

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 local storage.

Reference : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: But what if the browser does not support HTML5 storage?

Comment: localstorage is also bound to limits. Also please provide some more info in your answer, because the link will die making your answer only "Use HTML5 local storage." which is not really a pearl of an answer

Comment: He said more data, Local storage supports upto 5 MB in Chrome and 10 MB in IE.. Isn't That enough ??

Comment: I don't know. I have no idea what OP is doing. Hence my request for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross-browser compatible library [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) for this.

> jStorage is a cross-browser key-value store database to store data
>   locally in the browser - jStorage supports all major browsers, both in
>   desktop (yes - even Internet Explorer 6) and in mobile.
>
> Additionally jStorage is library agnostic, it works well with any
>   other JavaScript library on the same webpage, be it jQuery, Prototype,
>   MooTools or something else. Though you still need to have either a
>   third party library (Prototype, MooTools) or JSON2 on the page to
>   support older IE versions.